# Is AES GCM in the latest PHP broken or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

I tried implementing encryption in PHP using openssl_encrypt/decrypt. I tried using 128bit AES in GCM mode but then I noticed that even a one byte of the GCM tag is enough for decryption to be successful.

I googled a bit and found [this crypto.stackexchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177375/can-someone-explain-the-weird-treatment-of-the-openssl-aes-256-gcm-authenticatio) that encounters the same problem. The issue I am asking again is that this is over a 1 year old and this still doesnt seem to be fixed on the latest versions. I checked this on PHP Version 7.3.9-1 with OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019.

[Here is my code.](https://repl.it/@JanOupicky/AES-GCM-tag-useless)

```
$key = 'is_gcm_really_broken_on_php'; //27 bytes ... only need 16 but openssl doesnt use rest automatically. thats ok
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$tag = null;
$toEncrypt = 'hello world';
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($toEncrypt, 'aes-128-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
echo 'tag is ' . strlen($tag) . ' bytes<br>';
$encodedMsg = base64_encode($iv.$tag.$encrypted);
var_dump($encodedMsg);

//.... decrypting
echo '<br><br>decrypting<br>';

$decodedMsg = base64_decode($encodedMsg);
$msgIv = substr($decodedMsg, 0, 16);
$msgTag = substr($decodedMsg, 16, 1);
echo 'using tag thats ' . strlen($msgTag) . ' bytes<br>';
$msgToDecrypt = substr($decodedMsg, 32);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($msgToDecrypt, 'aes-128-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $msgIv, $msgTag);
echo 'decryption is ok.. no error<br>decrypted message is ' . $decrypted;
```

Is the code OK and PHP is still insecure in this matter (which is kinda crazy cause there is no warning about it in the documentation)? Or is the code wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is kinda OK and PHP is secure**

The problem here is how you use AES-GCM. The tag length is [a security parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Security), meaning you can choose any size. Minimal recommanded size is 96bits, **and you should check the size**.

In your code, you do not check the tag size, `openssl_decrypt()` does what you ask : validates a 1-byte tag.

PHP would know if this broke, see [test line 31](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/49a4e695845bf55e059e7f88e54b1111fe284223/ext/openssl/tests/openssl_decrypt_gcm.phpt)

Final thought : be careful when using low-level cryptography, you could use [Sodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) which is embedded with PHP>7.2

Comment: oh I understand now. it just cuts of the tag at the desired length and compares it. my assumption was that when I specify tag length at encryption the tag would be entirely different for different length but I see now that GCM just creates 128bit (blocksize) tag always. i guess having a warning in documentation about this wouldnt hurt.

Comment: @honzaik: I agree with you.

Comment: Agreed to, and that's why I advised a library doing it for you